# how to expand the viewport so that top and bottom menu bard can be seen in blender 2.8

Tags: 3d-view

The white band at top of the viewport is covering the top menu bar underneath and also the bottom menu bar is not fully visible. How to fix this?

Comment: Hello :). This shouldn't be happening, can you post a screenshot?

Comment: what if you toggle full screen (window > toggle full screen)? does it fix? 
what OS are you in? can you share a screenshot of the problem?